# Cloud Functions for Firebase: purchase trigger on test purchase

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to implement purchase verification using Cloud Functions for Firebase. Here is my `index.js`

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.updateDbOnPurchase = functions.analytics.event('in_app_purchase').onLog(event => {
    const uid = event.data.user.userId;
    const famKey = getFamKey(uid)
    console.log("UID: ${uid}, famKey: ${famKey}")
    admin.database().ref('/users/${uid}/famKey').then(snap => {
        if (snap.exists()) {
            admin.database().ref('/families/${famKey}/paydata/expire').set(Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000) + 2592000)
        }
    });
});
```

In my app I implemented In-App subscription, pushed APK to alpha track and made test purchase. But this code never triggered.

So, I have following questions:

1. Does In-App subscription works with `in_app_purchase` event?
2. Is it works with test purchases? Or I must test on real purchase?
3. Will event be triggered on subscription renewal?
4. Is it possible to get purchase SKU in this code?
5. In case of pirate using Freedom / Lucky Patcher will this code be triggered? Does Firebase performs purchase verification over Google Play, or I must implement it myself?

Comment: From the perspective of Firebase Analytics, I don't think that subscriptions count as in-app purchases.

Comment: @DougStevenson any arguments beside you thoughts? I need a clear answer. Or I'm spending 3 days on implementing what I need, or I will spend week trying to debug a thing, that shouldn't work by FA design. That's a big difference

Comment: I don't know all the answers.  I would suggest contacting email support to get some guaranteed attention.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a month delay (long time after I finished implementing it using Database trigger), I received answer from Firebase support:

> Hi Dima,
>
> Sorry for the delay in my response. Please see the answers to your
>   questions below:
>
> > 1. Does In-App subscription works with in_app_purchase event?
>
> In-App subscription does not trigger the in_app_purchase event, since
>   no renewal, refunds, monthly/early subscriptions are counted towards
>   in_app_purchases.
>
> > 2. Is it works with test purchases? Or I must test on real purchase?
>
> Firebase Analytics automatically filters out test purchases, so it
>   wouldn't trigger the function's "in_app_purchase" event.
>
> > 3. Will event be triggered on subscription renewal?
>
> Subscription renewal will not trigger the "in_app_purchase" event
>   because In-App Subscription does not trigger the "in_app_purchase"
>   event.
>
> > 4. Is it possible to get purchase SKU in this code?
>
> I assume that what you want to obtain is the product ID. You can
>   obtain the product ID by accessing the event.user.appInfo properties
>   from the function.
>
> > 5. In case of pirate using Freedom / Lucky Patcher will this code be triggered? Does Firebase performs purchase verification over Google
> >        Play, or I must implement it myself?
>
> Firebase Analytics performs some measure of purchase verification on
>   both iOS and Android. However, this only affects your analytics data.
>   If you want to combat piracy in your app, you need to implement
>   verification yourself.
>
> Let me know if you have any other questions.

Hope, this will be useful for someone